# NotFound page in Orchard CMS modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, orchardcms

When url starts with module area name, Orchard's NotFound page is not working.
Instead, it shows the standard 404 "Server Error in '/' Application."
e.g.
http://localhost:30320/users/test/
http://localhost:30320/orchard.medialibrary/test/

http://www.orchardproject.net/test12345 - NotFound.cshtml
http://www.orchardproject.net/users/test12345 - standard ASP.NET 404

When debugging, it throws an exception (HttpException: "The controller for path '***' was not found or does not implement IController").

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm, seems to be an core issue. When using custom routes containing a catch all route that redirects to a custom error page it works. Without the custom routes i also get the default MVC error page. This originates from the registration of the `OrchardControllerFactory` in `src\Orchard\Environment\OrchardStarter.cs` whereas this class redirects to default MVC functionality in `GetControllerInstance()` when a URL does not match a controller. Any ideas how to inject a custom factory class to do a redirect to a custom error page without altering the core code?